# Put simply, how does Ecto know that a struct is "Stale"

Tags: elixir, ecto

In the [Changeset documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html), it says:

> When a conflict happens (a record which has been previously fetched is being updated, but that same record has been modified since it was fetched), an Ecto.StaleEntryError exception is raised.

There are a number of conversations on StackOverflow, GitHub, and other places about how to fix various scenarios that involve a `StaleEntryError`. But there is no explanation of *how* Ecto knows that a struct is stale.

What is the underlying mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ecto.Changeset` [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#optimistic_lock/3-usage) you linked to is pretty self explanatory:

> Optimistic locking works by keeping a “version” counter for each record; this counter gets incremented each time a modification is made to a record. Hence, in order to use optimistic locking, a field must exist in your schema for versioning purpose. Such field is usually an integer but other types are supported.

Here's the [Ecto implementation](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/f7da0f032f80c2eaa3198360f74d6ab3457fc168/lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex#L590-L602).